# Adding color to the distorted portion of text

Tags: gimp

I am trying to add color to the distorted part of an image or text but can't seem to then clear the full back ground from the image as the initial image is no longer whole because of the distortion and the fill runs into my background. Let's see if I can explain this better.

1. I have distorted text which has transparency behind it.
2. I want to pull through a different color into that distorted text portion... but keep the transparent back ground.

This photos might help to explain slightly. I got frustrated and began to erase the background by hand. I want to keep the black with gold running through it portion, but erase all else. [image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not sure what you mean by distorted text.  I can't see any text in your example image.  Also it's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing how this has been constructed. Perhaps consider showing the layers panel. Perhaps you need to look into using layer masks for a job like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Color>Color to alpha`](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-filter-color-to-alpha.html) to remove the white by replacing it with transparency.

To change the color of the remaining bits, just use the ["alpha-lock"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#idm47137459937072) on the layer, then bucket-fill/paint/apply blend (without a selection). The alpha-lock will preserve opacity, and so will keep the transparent pixels transparent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I finally just ended up figuring it out by distressing the original image and then just layering a full gold image underneath the original distressed. Which allowed for the gold to show through. I will try this way as well and see if I can make it work. Still new to GIMP so I really appreciate your answer.